# Self Join to return distinct records in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, self-join

I an trying to retrieve the distinct records using the follow SQL Statement:

```
SELECT count (*) FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT pv1.docid, pv2.docid 
FROM Frequency pv1
INNER JOIN Frequency pv2
ON pv1.docid = pv2.docid
AND pv1.term="transactions"
AND pv2.term="world")x;
```

The schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE Frequency (
docid VARCHAR(255),
term VARCHAR(255),
count int,
PRIMARY KEY(docid, term);
```

I know that there are 187 docs containing term world and 26 containing transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to do this?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT pv1.[docid])
FROM
    Frequency AS pv1
JOIN
    Frequency AS pv2
        ON pv2.[docid] = pv1.[docid]
WHERE
    pv1.[term] = "transactions"
    AND pv2.[term] = "world"
```

This returns the count of unique docid's with the conditions you stipulated.

Comment: Unfortunately, that returns only 3 records.

Comment: @ChrisRigano then your data isn't represented as you think... This will find two rows with **matching** docids where one has one term and the other has another. You say 187 say "world" and 26 say "transactions" but only three distinct ones have the same docid.

Comment: That's it!!!! Matthew! Thanks do much ... I was trying to solve the wrong problem! I can now go to sleep ET NYC. thanks! Chris

Comment: @ChrisRigano remember to upvote helpful answers and mark the answer which solved your problem